# Lion best practice for Accessibility Trusted Processes

Tags: accessibility, osx-lion

I thought that I read somewhere that it was possible to flag an app as AXIsProcessTrusted True inside a plist or entitlement file in Lion.  Now that I'm searching for it, I don't see any documentation or best practice update newer than 2008.

Is it possible to make and app AXMakeProcessTrusted in its build (plist etc)?

If so or not, is it still going to require the user authenticating as root as the older docs state in order to enable this?

Finally, I am looking at the sample app UIElementInspector and I don't see *anywhere* that the app ever calls this function.  Why is it trusted then, and/or how can my app get the same level of access as this app with the minimal pain for the user?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part 3 definitively (not 1 and 2 though): UIElementInspector breaks if you turn on app sandboxing (as I had in my app - after all, the app isn't just for tinkering around).  Sandboxing apparently reduces Accessibility to only the local process (presumably unless AXMakeProcessTrusted has been executed successfully).

Comment: Ugh the sandbox sucks so bad.  Why does Apple have to be so responsible and proactive re: security!?!?  They're like an uptight grandma that hates disabled people and anyone who doesn't just sit in Safari and iPhoto all-day long.